# Update MySQL every 2 hours with API data

Tags: php, mysql

What is the best way to update my database with data every say 2 hours. I am going to be calling an API that returns JSON, and then I want to update that database. It is bringing back snow conditions.

Thanks,

Ryan

Comment: Standard formula: Cron job + PHP script

Answer (score 5):

It depends what kind of server you are on, but if it is linux based, you can use cron to run your php script every 2 hours.

The cron entry would be something like:

```
0 */2 * * * /path/to/script
```

And the script could be a shell script with the form (just an example for my server...):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. So I would have my file that runs my query, then the cron entry would go where?

Comment: @Coughlin The cron entry would go in crontab; you can manage that from the command line (some hosting providers have graphical tools as well). To see your current cron entries from the command line: `crontab -l` and to edit the file: `crontab -e`

Answer (score 3):

You can create events in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

```
CREATE EVENT e_hourly
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 2 HOUR
COMMENT 'a comment'
DO BEGIN  
  //Hourly action 
END
```

Running non-SQL command from within the DB-server is not recommended though due to security issues.
*(this is only possible through a custom UDF like: http://bernardodamele.blogspot.com/2009/01/command-execution-with-mysql-udf.html#!/2009/01/command-execution-with-mysql-udf.html )*

On windows the `at` command or scheduled tasks can run every 2 hours:
at: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565
scheduled tasks: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task

On Linux crontab is your friend: http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/schedule_tasks_on_linux_using_crontab/

Comment: mySQL can't make the API call and parse the JSON though, can it?

Comment: @Pekka, It can if you install a UDF that allows it to run shell-commands, but that's a security hole.

Answer (score 1):

Use cron and write some script that gets data from api and insert it to database.